# Windows 7 Firewall Resources

Tags: windows-7, firewall

I was trying to understand all the reasons for a program to ask the user to accept it at the user's firewall.

What resources do programs need that cause them to ask for the user permission to pass through the firewall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firewall is what protects your computer, at least somewhat, from being attacked from the outside via a connection to the internet. The programs more or less just ask user permission to pass through the firewall, therefore opening up a hole in the wall to allow the software to access resources on the net, such as automatic updates.

This in turn can, I don't mean will, but can lead to opening up a hole that would allow a attack, although if you keep the software up to date, that is not very likely.

Comment: Thank you user88311 Do you have any article for this topic?.

Comment: @uBlankText http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing), http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Firewall, http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/products/features/windows-firewall